# logstash schedule inserting duplicate records into elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I created logstash config file with JDBC input plugin to bring Oracle database tables into elasticsearch and i made it as schedule for every five minutes.

Its working as per expected but the problem is, its inserting duplicate records when it is running for 2nd, 3rd time. how can we avoid inserting duplication records into elasticsearch.?

Please find my logstash config file with JDBC input plugin

```
input {
      jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc8.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
        jdbc_user => "demo"
        jdbc_password => "1234567"
        schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
        statement => "select * from documents"
      }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "schedule1_documents"
      }
    }
```

please find my document table schema

```
id  ---> Not Null number
FileName ---> varchar2
Path     ----> varchar2
File_size ---> varchar2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the id field from your `documents` table. Otherwise, ES will create an id itself.

So your output should look like this instead:

```
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "schedule1_documents"
    document_id => "%{id}"              <-- add this line with the proper ID field
  }
```

Comment: Do we need to pass some value for this `"%{ID}"` ..? can you give some example

Comment: that's supposed to be the name of the ID field in your `documents` table.

Comment: if i give `document_id => "%{ID}"` all the documents are indexing with this id, actually its overriding with this `%{ID}`. Finally i have only one document in my index.

Comment: I've updated my answer, simply replace `%{ID}` by `%{id}`

Comment: Thank soo much Val., its working very nicely. Thanks for your help